# Is it okay to have duplicates in a array?

Tags: java

I'm working on my self project. A project that you will let you input the day and then the program gives you the day of given date.

Here's my array:

```
String []days = {"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday"};
```

My condition:

```
if(inputDate <= 6){
                  firstCase = yearsCode[0] + inputDate + 3 - 7;
                  System.out.println("January " + inputDate + " is " + days[firstCase]);}
```

I put the day Sunday and Monday again because if my input date is 5<7 it gives me the ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

I got the algorithm [here #6](http://www.architecturendesign.net/12-useful-math-hacks-that-they-didnt-teach-you-in-school/):

Comment: will need a lil more clarification. and you don't have to repeat the elements in array. Its not a restriction but in you case it's totally unnecessary

Comment: Remove the Sunday from the start and Monday from the end. Change the days[firstCase] to days[firstCase + 1] as in your algo sat is 6 and fri is 5 so index starts with 1.

Comment: Is it possible if I remove the last two days. After saturday it will go back at sunday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays don't care what you put in them, you can have several copies of an object in your array if you so desire.

However, to solve your problem more elegantly, you can ensure that the index you calculate never exceeds the number of elements in your array. For this, you can use the modulo operator %

```
   firstCase = yearsCode[0] + inputDate + 3 - 7;
   firstCase = firstCase % 7;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's OK to have duplication in an array but you might find a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I read the contents of link. Here is the solution.
Remove both Sunday and monday from last. You should only subtract with multiples of 7( do mod)  if the result is more than 6. 
So your code should be

```
  firstCase = (yearsCode[0] + inputDate + 3)%7;
  System.out.println("January " + inputDate + " is " + days[firstCase]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it OK to have duplicate values in an array?

```
new String[]{"yes", "yes", "and", "absolutely", "yes"};
```